# What does ':' in React-Native mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

A piece of **react-native** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Blink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isShowingText: true };

    // Toggle the state every second
    setInterval(() => (
      this.setState(previousState => (
        { isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText }
      ))
    ), 1000);
  }
```

what does "`:`" mean in the follwing lines?

```
 isShowingText: true 
 isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText
```

Comment: `:` is the "delimiter" between property name and value in JavaScript objects.

Comment: It separates the property name from the property value. It's object literal notation in JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals

Comment: @Tholle, so it like "=" in csharp? right?

Comment: To be clear, the curly braces are part of the syntax as well. `{...}` denote an object literal in that case. The general syntax is `{key: value, key2: value}`. I'd recommend to look at some JavaScript introductory material, e.g. on MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with React, this is just Javascript.  The line

```
previousState => (
        { isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText }
      )
```

is equivalent to

```
function(previousState) {
    const v = !previousState.isShowingText;
    const obj = {
     "isShowingText": v,
    };
    return obj;
}
```

The colon is the usual way of describing a key-value relationship in an object.

Answer (score 1):

It is way of representing/ assigning values like JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Same to **JavaScript** Objects that written with curly braces.

Object properties are written as `name:value` pairs , separated by commas.
like the following:

```
 var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
```

For More info Check the follwing Link:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_datatypes_object